# Selecting the max amount from mysql table

Tags: mysql, max

I have been trying to obtain the latest serial number of a particular product, so that I can show the next available serial number in my admin area.

Following is what I have been trying

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/093dd/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `serials` (
  `sn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `cxid` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itmid` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sn`)
);

INSERT INTO `serials` (`sn`, `cxid`, `itmid`) VALUES
('7', '00007', 'Name'),
('8', '00008', 'Name'),
('9', '00010', 'Name'),
('10', '00010', 'Name'),
('11', '00010', 'Name'),
('12', '00012', 'Name'),
('13', '00013', 'Name');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    sn
  FROM serials AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(sn) AS one FROM serials where cxid = '00010') AS s ON s.one = t.sn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/093dd/1/0)**:

I always get an empty result no matter what I do. What might be the problem? Maybe there is a much easier way?

And the point to note is that I have to get the serial only of a particular product, NOT from the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the right field?  `itmid = 0010`?  Shouldn't it be `cxid`?

You also have no values matching `0010`.  You should use `'00010'`.  I'm fairly certain `0010` will not equal `00010` when you are using a varchar data type and you should wrap it in quotes to evaluate it as a string.

Lastly, `sn` from the looks of it should be an integer type.  Without it being an integer, MAX() won't work correctly.  There is a workaround for this if you are certain you need it as a varchar you can use ABS:

```
SELECT MAX(ABS(sn)) AS one FROM serials where cxid = '00010'
```

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the actual correctly. Still no luck!

Comment: I cannot add values to sn if it is `int`

Comment: @Sid What isn't working?  The SQL fiddle works with my SQL query above.  You don't seem to need a join, your join isn't doing anything and what do you mean by add values?

Comment: @Sid, from the looks of it, the values you provided in the fiddle don't match your usage.  Maybe you should include some more detailed information and some real values so I understand what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using wrong field.

**Use this :**

```
SELECT sn FROM serials AS t INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(sn) AS one FROM serials where cxid = '00010') AS s ON s.one = t.sn
```

You should use `'00010'` instead of `'0010'`. because you have no values matching `0010`.

Comment: @Sid..try only this SELECT MAX(ABS(sn)) AS one FROM serials where cxid = '00010'

Comment: @RohitJindal, you really shouldn't add answers unless you are expanding on something.  You seem to almost have copied the top half of my answer and just added the query.

Comment: @Devon your answer is helpful thats why i address Sid to do this.

Comment: @RohitJindal, that is what upvoting or commenting is for.  Adding duplicate answers is unnecessary and just adds more data for people to have to sort through.

Comment: @Devon..its my mistake..i just add comment that is similar to your answer.otherwise answer is given by me is mine.